# SQL Query - Case with different then portions

Tags: sql

I need to calculate what half of the financial year an agreement falls within.

If it is between July and December, it is H1.
If it is between January and June, it is H2

As a note, the agreements can last over multiple years, so i use the AgreementEndDate closes to today to determine the financial year.  This portion of the code works (i.e. `min(case when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate then AgreementEndDate else '' end) as 'Agreement End Date'`)

However, here is where I am running into problem.  I need to add either H1 or H2 to the end of the 'Agreement Window' and haven't figure it out yet.

I tried adding multiple WHEN clauses, however, I get duplicate rows.  That why I went with min.

Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATE
SET @dtDate = GETDATE();
Select 
    AD.TPID
    ,min(case when AgreementEffectiveDate<=@dtDate then AgreementEffectiveDate else '' end) as 'Agreement Effective Date'
    ,min(case when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate then AgreementEndDate else '' end) as 'Agreement End Date'
    ,min(case when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate then 'FY' + convert(varchar(2),(FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H2'
            --WHEN (month(AgreementEndDate) >= 1 and month(AgreementEndDate) <= 6)  THEN 'FY' + convert(varchar(2),(FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H2'
            --WHEN (month(AgreementEndDate) >= 7 and month(AgreementEndDate) <= 12)  THEN 'FY' + convert(varchar(2),(FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H1'
            else '' end) as 'Agreement Window'
   from AgreementDetails AD
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... here is the solution.

```
,min(case   when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate  and ((month(AgreementEndDate) >= 1 and month(AgreementEndDate) <= 6))  THEN 'FY' + convert(varchar(2),(FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H2'
            when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate  and ((month(AgreementEndDate) >= 7 and month(AgreementEndDate) <= 12))  THEN 'FY' + convert(varchar(2),(FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H1'
        else '' end) as 'Agreement Window'
```